# Installing MagicDraw “libjvm.dylib” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified on mac M2 pro

Tags: macos, magic-draw

I installed MagicDraw 190_sp3 on my mac but it couldn't be opened. When I try to open it shows the error that the developer couldn't be verified. Can anyone help me in this regard, please?

Answer (score 0):

Is your macOS showing an error alert like below?

[image]

If so, your app is not signed and notarized.

**If you’re certain that an app you want to install is from a trustworthy source and hasn’t been tampered with, you can temporarily override your Mac security settings to open it.**

If you still want to open an app for which the developer cannot be verified, open `System Preferences. Go to` Security & Privacy. Make sure `Allowed apps downloaded from` is set to `App Store and identified developers.` Click the `Open Anyway` button in the General pane to confirm your intent to open or install the app.

[image]

The warning prompt reappears, and if you're absolutely sure you want to open the app anyway, you can click Open.

[image]

The app is now saved as an exception to your security settings, and you can open it in the future by double-clicking it, just as you can any authorized app.

See [this KB](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491) from apple for details

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer [kakaiikaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2626737/kakaiikaka).

I did all of those steps but it was still showing the problem, then I found out the problem was with my **JDK version on my JVM**. So, I **installed JDK version 8** and again tried to open this and it worked as a charm!